# Have more than one Build button for a parameter based job

Tags: jenkins, button, build, parameters

In Jenkins, I created a job with parameters (string, validating string, choice, dynamic choice, blah de blah etc kind).

Now, When I go to the job, I see "**Build with Parameters**" link on the left hand side. I click on it and I see a nice parameter/arguments (what I configured in the job) on HTML front.

At the bottom of these parameters, there's a button "**Build**" (This means, once you provide the values to the parameters and click the Build button, it'll initiate the Jenkins job and whatever the job's is configured to do (with/without those arguments/parameters passed), it'll do it.

Now, what I need is:

1. Is there's any way, I can have two or more of such "Build" buttons at the same time? i.e. PS attached image.
2. If only one Build box is allowed/available, can I place a check box (a parameter), which when checked/unchecked, change the number / name of parameters for this job.

[image]

Comment: How did you solve this? Are you still using the Dynamic Parameter Plugin?

Comment: The way I resolved it was, I had to pick all parameters using single Jenkins job. If you don't want a single jenkins job, then you can think of having an Upstream/parent job and call a downstream/child job (parameters passing). Anyways, using `Active Choice Plugin` parameters (simple, reflective etc), I was able to (write simple Groovy if-then-else conditions) to set the values of some parameters depending upon a value / selection (i.e. true/false in case of checkbox type variable or a user entered/selected value) of another paramter which was listed first in the Build with Parameters page.

Comment: Then, within the Jenkins job, I made the Jenkins job intelligent enough to look for those variables whether they have a/some valid value(s) OR have NA/Null/NotSet/Custom/Blank values and then triggered operations directly or via other Jenkins jobs to drive the workflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you actually looking for, but maybe this plugin can help:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in

This way you'll be able to change the parameters by the answer of the user's input, and build accordingly.

Hopes this helps

Comment: exactly.. found the same.